# Как обработать пустую ячейку DATETIM

Tags: java, mysql

Есть таблица в базе mysql, в которой есть поле DATETIME. Это поле может быть null. Когда выполняю SELECT к этой таблице и получаю данные таким способом

```
 Date date = resultSet.getDate("date_birth")
```

то при null в этом поле вылетает ошибка. Как обработать null поле datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь и за то что так быстро откликнулись. Решение было следующим. В строку подключения к БД нужно было добавить

```
zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Что бы она приняла вид типо такого

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbhelper?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

тогда null значения полей DATE будут конвертироваться в java null

Comment: А зачем Вы присвоили запросу тег `mysql`? если решили корректировать не на уровне mysql, а на уровне коннектора?

Comment: потому что другого способа не нашел

Comment: Есть их у mysql. Вот только Вы как-то не сказали, во что намерены превращать Null на уровне клиентской программы. Впрочем, это не так важно - в любом случае такую конвертацию из вызывающего проблемы Null в нечто беспроблемное (ноль, пустая строка, 1900-01-01 и т.п.) можно выполнять непосредственно на сервере БД, функцией COALESCE или её младшей сестрой IFNULL. И при этом получать код, который работает независимо от настроек соединения.

Comment: В том то и дело, что нужно было получить null из бд, без конвертации. То есть, если в бд в этом поле null, мне не нужно что бы мне приходило '1900-01-01', а нужно что бы приходило null

Comment: Тогда возражения снимаются. Хотя я бы предложил добавить тег `mysqlconnector` как более подходящий (правда, следует признать, что популярность у него никакая).